# find_in_batches "NO BLOCK GIVEN (YIELD)"

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, find, block, yield

I have a method where I take in a model and result_size . The first thing i try to do in this method is:

```
array = model.logs.find_in_batches(:batch_size => result_size)
```

But this doesn't work; instead it returns "No Block Given (Yield)". I guess I'm just unfamiliar with blocks and yields. If anyone could help me understand/fix this problem I would greatly appreciate it!

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 6):

`find_in_batches` expects you to pass the values into a block, as so:

```
model.logs.find_in_batches(:batch_size => result_size) do |models|
  models.each do |model|
    model.do_something
  end
end
```